# Can't update table in mysql in a Grails application

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, grails, grails-orm

I have this weird problem. I have a **User** domain class in a **Grails** app. The class is as follows:

```
class User {

transient springSecurityService

String username
String name
String password
String email
String company
Date activationDate
String contactPhone
boolean enabled
boolean passwordExpired = false
boolean accountExpired
boolean accountLocked
boolean isDeleted=false
boolean isPrimary
String jobTitle 
String jobFunction
String deskPhone
String mobile
String profilePicURL
boolean isLinkExpired=false
UserType userType
Date dateCreated
Date lastUpdated

static constraints = {
    password nullable: true
    company nullable: true
    email blank: false, unique: true
    name nullable: true
    activationDate nullable:true
    username nullable: true
    enabled nullable: false
    isDeleted nullable: false
    passwordExpired nullable: false
    jobFunction nullable:true
    jobTitle nullable:true
    contactPhone nullable:true
    mobile nullable:true
    profilePicURL nullable:true
    deskPhone nullable:true
    userType nullable:true

}
static auditable = true
static mapping = {
    password column: '`password`'
    tablePerHierarchy false
    cache true 
}

Set<Role> getAuthorities() {
    UserRole.findAllByUser(this).collect { it.role } as Set
}
```

And there is a method **activeDeactiveUser** which enables/disables user authorization for some functionality as follows:

```
def activeDeactiveUser(String username) {
    def user = User.findByUsername(username)

    if (user.enabled == false)
        user.enabled = true
    else
        user.enabled = false

    if (user.validate()) {
        user.save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
    } else {
        user.errors.allErrors.each {
            print it
        }
    }

    def userJson = new JSONObject()
    userJson.put("isEnabled", user.enabled)

    return userJson
}
```

When the app is running on **localhost**, the table is updating fine. But when the same code is running on **server**, the table fails to update. I don't know why it's behaving like this.
The app isn't raising any exception on the save method on localhost. May be the problem is with different versions of **mysql** on my machine and the server. Is there any the to debug the app while it is running on the server?

The app is hosted in an AWS EC2 instance running Ubuntu 14.04 and **Grails** version 2.4.3. The database is stored in an AWS RDS instance running **mysql** 5.5.40.

Comment: what are commands you have use create war file @theleancoder?

Comment: i thing your deploying previous old war file to server.

Comment: before creating war please run "grails clean" and "grails create war" command.

Comment: The command is grails -Dgrails.env=staging war ROOT.war

Comment: No, I'm deploying the latest war each time by pulling the latest repo from github

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. The same code is written in old wars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126903/discussion-between-dipak-thoke-and-theleancoder).

Answer (score 0):

there are many reasons for it - I think you need to provide more information for yourself and in this thread so we can help.
I suggest, first add log information by one of the options:

1. you can add logSql to dataSource file:

   ```
    dataSource {
           logSql = true
    }
   ```
2. to produce far more readable SQL commands than simply logSql would do add the following properties in DataSource.groovy:

   ```
   hibernate {
         format_sql = true
         use_sql_comments = true
   }
   ```

   Then, add the following log4j settings to Config.groovy:

   ```
   log4j = {
        debug 'org.hibernate.SQL'
        trace 'org.hibernate.type'
    }
   ```

   The first setting logs the SQL commands, the second one logs the bound parameters and the bindings of the result set.

the issue can also be related to schema update - so maybe your local DB schema is not in sync with server one. you ned to check field type and constraints.

Comment: Which file should I look for the logs generated by above configuration?